# How can I pass an object to a JSP tag?

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags, el

I have a JSP page that contains a scriplet where I instantiate an object.  I would like to pass that object to the JSP tag without using any cache.

For example I would like to accomplish this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="wf" uri="JspCustomTag" %>

<% 
 Object myObject = new Object();
%>

<wf:my-tag obj=myObject />
```

I'm trying to avoid directly interacting with any of the caches (page, session, servletcontext), I would rather have my tag handle that.

Comment: Note, i don't want my object converted to a string and passed as a string, i want my tag handler to actually have access to the object.

Comment: Do you care to choose the right answer?

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo All of them are bad.

Comment: @peterh, Well they aren't all *that* bad.

Answer (score 43):

A slightly different question that I looked for here: "How do you pass an object to a tag file?"

Answer: Use the "type" attribute of the attribute directive:

```
<%@ attribute name="field" 
              required="true"
              type="com.mycompany.MyClass" %>
```

The type [defaults to java.lang.String](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPTags5.html#wp89854), so without it you'll get an error if you try to access object fields saying that it can't find the field from type String.

Comment: Not this was the question, -1.

Answer (score 11):

```
<jsp:useBean id="myObject" class="java.lang.Object" scope="page" />
<wf:my-tag obj="${myObject}" />
```

Its not encouraged to use Scriptlets in JSP page. It kills the purpose of a template language.

Comment: First, the paged scope is a very bad thing. Second: it first serializes myObject and then deserializes. This solution is much worser as a simple scriptlet.

Comment: 1. What is wrong with `page` scoped beans? 2. There is no serialisation taking place here. Why do you think that?

Comment: Finally I understood you have right, so you have the bounty.

Answer (score 5):

The original syntax was to reuse '<%= %>'

So

```
<wf:my-tag obj="<%= myObject %>" />
```

See [this part of the Sun Tag Library Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tutorial/TagLibraries16.html#62510) for an example

Comment: Link is broken. See the Web Archive version [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20090130012629/http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tutorial/TagLibraries16.html).

Comment: It first serializes myObject and then deserializes. Very bad solution.

Comment: Had a similar problem, this solved it. Didn't get the problem on serialization and deserialization, since it is transparent -- didn't had to do anything on the tag handler.

Answer (score 3):

For me expression language works only if I make that variable accessible, by putting it for example in page context.

```
<%  Object myObject = new Object();
    pageContext.setAttribute("myObject", myObject);
%>
<wf:my-tag obj="${myObject}" />
```

Otherwise tas receives null.

And `<wf:my-tag obj="<%= myObject %>" />` works with no additional effort. Also <%=%> gives jsp compile-time type validation, while El is validated only in runtime.

Comment: It first serializes myObject and then deserializes. Very bad solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "<%= %>" to get the object value directly in your tag :

```
    <wf:my-tag obj="<%= myObject %>"/>
```

and to get the value of any variable within that object you can get that using "obj.parameter" like:

```
<wf:my-tag obj="<%= myObject.variableName %>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use expression language:

```
    <wf:my-tag obj="${myObject}" />
```

Comment: We need to add that in some context, prior using it.

Comment: It first serializes myObject and then deserializes. Very bad solution.