# How can I reuse code in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

For example, a user will be rendered throughout my application as

```
<div class="user">
  <p class="username">${user.name}</p>
  <p class="karma">${user.karma}</p>
  <img src="/users/${user.id}"/>
</div>
```

How can I reuse this code block?

Note - my code is running within a tag, so I can't use tags for this (or any JSP) otherwise I get a `Scripting elements are disallowed here` error.

**Edit**

I'm trying to use a tag file, but getting PropertyNotFoundException.

This is my tag file called 'user.tag':

```
<%@tag description="User" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>

<a href="../user/showUser.do?userId=${user.id}">
    <p>${user.name}</p>
    <img class='avatar' src='${user.avatarUrl}' alt=""/>
</a>
```

And usage inside a jsp:

Where job.poster is a java bean with `id`, `name`, and `avatarUrl` properties.
If I add

```
<%@attribute name="user" %>
```

to the tag file, then I get an exception

```
Property 'id' not found on type java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since JSP 2.0, there is yet another kind of tags: Tag files. Tag files are JSP custom tags written as a JSP template itself, which seems to be what you want.

http://fforw.de/post/creating-jsp-layouts-with-page-tags/ shows how to use such a tag file as general layout solution. Using them as component should be even easier.

Comment: Please see my edited question - I would like to use a tag file, but so far it's a no go.

Comment: I found the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75626/how-do-i-pass-an-object-to-a-jsp-tag/1228031#1228031

Comment: @fforw the link is dead.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use tag files within tag files; this works for me in a JSP 2.2 container:

```xml
<%-- mytag.tag --%>
<%@tag description="demo code" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="cust" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<%@attribute name="message"%>
<cust:mytag2 message="${message}" /><%-- uses mytag2.tag --%>
```

If that fails, you can use the include directive: `<%@include file="/WEB-INF/jspf/fragment.jspf" %>`

Note that the spec says about tags:

```or-tag-here
Directive Available? Interpretation/Restrictions
======================================================================
page      no         A tag file is not a page. The tag directive must
                     be used instead. If this directive is used in a
                     tag file, a translation error must result.
```

So, `fragment.jspf` must not have a any elements that are not supported in tags, including a `page` directive.

Answer (score 1):

For the example you have given it sounds like some templating framework is needed, to display the user badge on each screen.  At its simplest level this may just be a jsp:include which always includes your "UserBadge.jsp".

If you are running on a web framework e.g. JSF you may use Facelet templates or write a custom component for this.  So the answer depends on what framework you have.  Breaking it down to just JSP and JSTL - the included JSP or a javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag would certainly reduce the duplication.

Always be careful to follow the DRY Principle... Don't Repeat Yourself!

Comment: I would like to use a tag for this, but not sure exactly how to define it. Could you point me towards a code sample?

Answer (score 0):

I feel sometimes creating a .tag file is overkill (especially if it's only for one page), and I've wanted what you describe for years, so I wrote my own, simple solution.  See here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25575120/1607642

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use a custom tag or jsp functions.

Thanks,

Comment: You mean: ***Why don't you use a custom tag or jsp functions?*** right?

Comment: Updated my question to explain why.

Comment: And, being picky, I think the title should be JSTL not JSLT.

Comment: @ripper234 a tag can also contain jsp. Make that tag body as JSP. It should work.

Comment: What do you mean by "Make that tag body as JSP" ?

Comment: A tag can itself contain a jsp in between. For ex, for a tag display, this is how it looks:

<taglib:display arg="${value}">
 <taglib:showuserinfo/>
<taglib:display>

You can also go with jsp functions.